# How to upload image using phpunit and selenium?

Tags: php, image, selenium, automation, phpunit

I tried to upload the image using the below code, test case executing successfully but it's not upload the image for the specified path. Please find the below code and i'm using ubuntu system

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

use Athena\Athena;
use Athena\Test\AthenaBrowserTestCase;
use Tests\Browser\Page\GooglePage;
use Tests\Browser\Page\LocalFileDetector;

class DummyBrowserTest extends AthenaBrowserTestCase
{
    private $browser;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->browser = Athena::browser(true);
    }

    public function testGoogle_WaitForElementExistenceAndClick_ShouldShowResultsPage()
    {
        $this->browser = Athena::browser()->get('https://in.logs.com/');
        $this->browser
             ->find()
             ->elementWithName('email')
             ->sendKeys('aaaaaa+552@aaa.com');
        $this->browser
             ->find()
             ->elementWithName('password')
             ->sendKeys('aaaa');
        $this->browser
             ->find()
             ->elementWithXPath('//*[@id="loginform"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/button')
             ->click();
        $this->browser
             ->find()
             ->elementWithXPath('//a[contains(.,"Add car")]')
             ->click();  
        $this->browser
             ->find()
             ->elementWithXPath('//a[contains(.,"Browse Files")]')
             ->click()  
             ->sendKeys("/home/mohan/Desktop/indica.jpg");
        $this->browser
             ->find()
             ->elementWithXPath('//button[contains(.,"Save")]')
             ->click(); 
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance